# Log base b x in Linux x86-64 Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to program a logarithm function in Assembly, which takes in two arguments: the base (32-bit integer), and a value x (64-bit floating point).

The idea I currently have to do this is to use FYL2X and FDIVP by using the property of logarithms.

Since log (base a) b = (log (base 10) b / log (base 10) a), then I believe I can implement a logarithm function. How should I set it up in the registers for FPU, since I can't use XMM?

Answer (score 2):

So, here is an commented example that compute the log2 of a binary integer (with `bsr`) and that convert it to a decimal base through the FPU. The code is in x86 (i386) but can be easily converted to x86-64 (amd64).

The trickiest part is about the manipulation of the CW (FPU control word). Except that, it is more or less self-explanatory if you are used to the "my registers are used as a stack" thing.

```
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    movl    $1024, %eax ;; pushing the integer (1024) to analyze
    bsrl    %eax, %eax  ;; bit scan reverse (give the smallest non zero index)
    inc     %eax        ;; taking the 0th index into account

    pushl   %eax        ;; saving the previous result on the stack

    fildl   (%esp)      ;; loading the previous result to the FPU stack (st(0))
    fldlg2              ;; loading log10(2) on the FPU stack
    fmulp   %st, %st(1) ;; multiplying %st(0) and %st(1) and storing result in %st(0)

    ;; We need to set the FPU control word to 'round-up' 
    ;; (and not 'round-down' which is the default)
    fstcw  -2(%esp)      ;; saving the old FPU control word
    movw   -2(%esp), %ax ;; storing the FPU control word in %ax
    andw   $0xf3ff, %ax  ;; removing everything else
    orw    $0x0800, %ax  ;; setting the proper bit to '1'
    movw   %ax, -4(%esp) ;; getting the value back to memory
    fldcw  -4(%esp)      ;; setting the FPU control word to the proper value

    frndint              ;; rounding-up st(0)

    fldcw  -2(%esp)      ;; restoring the original FPU control word

    fistpl (%esp)        ;; loading the final result to the stack
    popl   %eax          ;; setting the return value to be our result

    leave
    ret
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Just do use FPU instructions and registers, XMM instructions and registers have nothing to do with those.

Use the `FLD` and `FILD` instructions to load floating point values and integer values into the FPU register stack.

If you don't have a CPU reference, now would be a good time to go to intel.com and download it. For free.

Answer (score 1):

FDIVP divides `st(0)` by `st(1)`, which means, you have to first load the divisor, then calculate the logarithm, and finalize with FDIVP.

OTOH, the function of `FYL2X` is  ST(1) = ST(1) * Log2(ST(0)); followed by pop st(0);

One can thus calculate the reciprocal of log2(base) and use that as the multiplier of FYL2X.
Furthermore, it probably makes sense to tabulate a few of those values and use something like:

```
  shl bx, 3
  fld inv_log_base[bx]
  fld argument
  fyl2x
```